# How to cycle through applications in current space on Mac OS?

Tags: macos, window

I want to separate my applications for personal use from those I use for work.

Working on a different desktop doesn't solve anything, since I use Cmd-Tab and Cmd-` exclusively to switch between windows, and I still see all the applications from the other desktops.

What is the way to achieve distraction-free Alt-Tabbing between only work applications while leaving my personal applications open?

Comment: I'd set up each app or 'set' of apps all simultaneously visible [pointless if you switch to a Space & still can't see what you're looking for] on different Spaces & swap using key commands. That way when you switch spaces you know which app you're switching to.

Comment: Yeah, you're going to have to elaborate on that one. Googling 'mac os app visible' or 'mac os app invisible' yields nothing significant.

Comment: mhm, not by changing visibility, simply by having specific apps for specific purposes in specific spaces... For instance, I have Finder, Safari, Calendar & messages on 1, my spreadsheet stuff on 2, music on 3, mail & related on 4, Video editing on 5, Photoshop on 6... You then just need to learn which is which & ctrl/number will take you straight there